# Html web storage

Tags: html

I have to store value using HTML local storage. But i am not storing values directly. Values are coming from from xml which i am parsing. Please help me out how should i store the values.

The snippet code is in javascript is:

```
function html5_storage_support() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] == null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

unction checekAnswer() {
    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled","true");
    $("#btnSubmit").attr("onclick","");


    attempted_count++;
    var feedback=question[i].getElementsByTagName("feedback");
    var answer=question[i].getElementsByTagName("answer"); 
    var score=question[i].getElementsByTagName("score"); 
    var left=question[i].getElementsByTagName("answer")[0].getAttribute("left");
    var top=question[i].getElementsByTagName("answer")[0].getAttribute("top");
    var single=question[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].getAttribute("single");

    if(answer[0].getAttribute("mcq")=="true")    
    {
        var ans=$('input:radio[name=rdOptions]:checked').val(); 
        var correct;
        var option=answer[0].getElementsByTagName("options");

        for(var k=0;k<option.length;k++)
        {
            if(option[k].getAttribute("correctAnswer")=="true")
            {
                correct=option[k].getAttribute("value");
            }
        }

        if(ans==correct)
        { 
            correctAnswers++;             
            $("#feedback").html("Correct Answer:"+ans+"<br/>");
            $("#feedback").append(score[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            $("#feedback").append("<br/>");
            $("#feedback").append(feedback[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#feedback").html("Your Answer:"+ans+"<br/>");
            $("#feedback").append("Correct Answer:"+correct+"<br/>");
            $("#feedback").append(score[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            $("#feedback").append("<br/>");
            $("#feedback").append(feedback[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
        }
    } 
    else 
    {

        $("#draggableImg").draggable({disabled:true});
        var diff=0;

        if(single=="true")
            diff=2;
        else
            diff=7;

        if(xPos<=(parseInt(left)+7) && xPos>=(parseInt(left)-7) && yPos<=(parseInt(top)+diff) && yPos>=(parseInt(top)-diff))
        {
            **//Displaying the feedbacks and scores**                     
            correctAnswers++;
            $("#feedback").append(score[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            $("#feedback").append("<br/>");
            $("#feedback").append(feedback[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
        }
        else
        {
            $("#feedback").html(score[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            $("#feedback").append("<br/>");
            $("#feedback").append(feedback[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
        }

        //$("#counter").html("left="+xPos+",top="+yPos);    
        $("#trFeedBack").show("slow");  
        display_nav(j,obj)  
    }
} // end function
```

Comment: My query is solved ... I just put local storage get item and set item n all is working well. But I have one query. I have applied page navigation. Suppose i have 5 pages and after submitting value it switch to another page but local storage is taking last submitted value. But i want if i am at page 3 n i am switching to page 1 then it show me 1st page value for 2nd page, 2nd page value. How in this way can be done? please give your suggestions

Comment: If you solved your problem, can you write an answer and validate it?